# Web chat to Desktop chat

Tags: c#, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, websocket

thanks for taking the time to read this.

At work we have a custom Winform C# chat app, I developed that app including the server for the application. it works fine, no problem there. it works like a messenger, where i can have several conversation at once.

What I need now is to port that chat app from desktop to a mobile enviroment, we are using HTML5, Javascritp, Jquery and WebSockets but i don't seem to find a way to connect both the mobile app and the desktop app.

I can send a chat message from the mobile to the desktop using a webservice and it works, but i don't have a way to return a message to the webapp from the desktop.

this is what i have:

- Desktop client: Winform C#
- Server: Winform C#

What i was thinking is to modify the Server so that when a desktop sends a message, it can detect if the user is connected on mobile or on desktop and do the regular sending stuff.

but once again i don't how to connect both kind of apps. Can it be done? can you provide me with an example(found none on google)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `winforms` is a terribly bad and inadequate choice [for an application Server].

Comment: Have you looked at asp.net signalr: http://signalr.net/

Comment: Just take the [SignalR Chat Room Example](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) and put the whole thing in the browser.  It's literally already written

Comment: @HighCore maybe i didn't explained well, is not a server as it is, is just an application that redirects the message to whoever needs to receive it.

Comment: @Darkelflemurian that's called a `server`. and winforms is a terribly bad and inadequate choice of technology for that, or anything else I can possibly imagine.

Comment: @ezanker i did check signalr.net before posting but i don't think that will be useful since this is going to cellphones.

Comment: @HighCore what do you suggest then? you are saying that server is terrible and stuff but that is not the original question.

Comment: @darkelflemurian If you need an application **Server**, look at using WCF, ASP.Net Web API, or any of the multiple technologies that .Net offers on that front. `winforms` is a (really old, poor) UI framework which has nothing to do with "redirecting messages" or anything like that.

Comment: @HighCore I need to connect the mobile app to the desktop app and be able to send from mobile to desktop(that is not a problem) and be able to receive from desktop to mobile(this is where the problem is)

Comment: @Darkelflemurian you don't "send stuff" to a mobile. If that was possible it'd be a terrible security hole. Create a proper Server and have the clients (both Windows and mobile) communicate to that.

Comment: @HighCore what do you suggest then? any example? any link? that is the reason i am asking is because I need a solution, an idea, or a proper direction on what to do. If i want someone to yell at me, simple i just go to my mom's and ask her to do so, period.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384398.aspx